# Customizing memoir

Tags: margins, memoir

I wish to set a page with the following measures (I'm copying a Renaissence text, basically):

> - Stocksize (a3paper)
> - trimmedsize (papersize) 340mm*210mm
> - typeblock 261.8mm*140mm
> - lr margins 23.3mm 46.7mm
> - ul margins 23.3mm 54.9mm
> - marginnote dst 2.8mm, width 23.3mm, 1em

Fontsize should be roman `14pt` and marginnote text should be italic `12pt`

Now maybe I'm overlooking something, but it appears memoir sets the text margins according to the stock and keeps moving the trims over the text.

```
\documentclass[a3paper, 14pt, twoside, showtrims]{memoir}

\settrimmedsize{340mm}{210mm}{*}
%\settrims{10mm}{10mm}
%\settypeblocksize{261.8mm}{140mm}{*}
%\setlrmargins{23.3mm}{46.7mm}{*}
\setlrmarginsandblock{23.3mm}{46.7mm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{23.3mm}{54.9mm}{*}

\setmarginnotes{2.8mm}{23.3mm}{1em}


\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum \sidepar{\lipsum}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

I'm sure it's going to be a very trivial matter and I apologize if the answer is obvious, but I really can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: try to add \checkandfixthelayout at the end of your settings of page layout.

Comment: I would like to avoid \checkandfixthelayout, it kind of fixes the page but I don't know what's the actual result. I don't know how far from the original project it goes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Memoir Page Layout doesn't work as expected: Text shifted right](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24595/memoir-page-layout-doesnt-work-as-expected-text-shifted-right)

Comment: As stated I have no control on how \checkandfix modifies the layout. Xelatexing my code, I get the trims OVER the text, which is very peculiar, and different from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24595/memoir-page-layout-doesnt-work-as-expected-text-shifted-right

Comment: If you do not use \checkandfixthelayout, you have to use another margin-setting package, for example `geometry`. You may also try http://www.ctan.org/pkg/zwpagelayout

Comment: I realized you can type the resulting layout using \typeoutlayout The only problem is that it shows every value in pts, which means you have to recalculate everything in mms.

Comment: So far \checkandfixthelayout has produced a \marginparwidth almost TWICE as large as set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a3paper, 14pt, twoside, showtrims]{memoir}

\settrimmedsize{340mm}{210mm}{*}
%\settrims{10mm}{10mm}
%\settypeblocksize{261.8mm}{140mm}{*}
%\setlrmargins{23.3mm}{46.7mm}{*}
\setlrmarginsandblock{23.3mm}{46.7mm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{23.3mm}{54.9mm}{*}
\setmarginnotes{2.8mm}{23.3mm}{1em}

\settypeoutlayoutunit{mm} % <-- remember

\checkandfixthelayout % <-- remember

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum \sidepar{\lipsum}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

reports

```
*********************************************************
Stock height and width: 419.99507mm by 296.9965mm
Top and edge trims: 0mm and 0mm
Page height and width: 339.996mm by 209.99753mm
Text height and width: 263.38089mm by 139.87936mm
Spine and edge margins: 23.29971mm and 46.69945mm
Upper and lower margins: 23.29971mm and 53.31538mm
Headheight and headsep: 6.15047mm and 7.61998mm
Footskip: 10.15971mm
Columnsep and columnseprule: 3.51456mm and 0mm
Marginparsep and marginparwidth: 2.79996mm and 23.29971mm
Sidecapsep and sidecapwidth: 2.46019mm and 50.60962mm
Sidebarhsep and sidebarwidth: 2.46019mm and 50.60962mm
Sidebarvsep and sidebartopsep: 6.15047mm and 0mm
Sidebarheight: 330.28046mm
Sidefoothsep and sidefootwidth: 2.46019mm and 50.60962mm
Sidefootvsep and sidefootheight: 6.15047mm and 330.28046mm
*********************************************************
```

Comment: This fixes the issue. Thank you so much! I guess changing the font size and face of the marginpar section is another issue in itself.

Comment: For marginpar font try `\renewcommand{\sideparfont}{\normalfont\itshape\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont\small}`

Comment: @daleif There is a `$` char instead of `%` in your code :-)

Comment: @cornelius `\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont‌​\small` does not make much sense.

Comment: @daleif: Sorry, there is a typo: `\renewcommand{\sideparfont}{\normalfont\itshape\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont‌​}`